# Bind key to paste clipboard selection

Tags: x11, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts

My keyboard has a Menu key, when it's pressed I want to paste from CLIPBOARD selection (not PRIMARY).

I have got something working using sxhkd, xvkbd, and xsel:

```
Menu
    xvkbd -no-jump-pointer -xsendevent -text "$(xsel --output --clipboard)"
```

But it's a bit laggy and I am looking for something simpler.

Comment: How are you using `sxhkd`? It's not mentioned in the example. Also, I have `xvkbd 3.8` and nothing is printed with `-xsendevent` but I get output after removing it. Are you sure it works for you?